# How do I set permissions for a namespaced controller in CanCan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, cancancan

I have a "supervisor" role that is basically a limited admin for my app, but I'm having trouble giving it the appropriate permissions. Specifically, I have a controller `/controllers/admin/dashboard_controller.rb` which I want the supervisor role to be able to manage.

In `activity.rb` I have this:

```
if current_user.is_supervisor?
  can :manage, Dashboard
end
```

and the response I get when I try to hit any method in `Admin::DashboardController` is this:

```
uninitialized constant Ability::Dashboard
```

on the same line that I'm specifying the former.

I'm doing a `can :manage, Dashboard`, but I'm still getting a forbidden response from that. How can I let cancan know that the class is a level deeper than `/controllers/`?

Conclusion: I'm going to move away from CanCan for this project because it doesn't handle the breadth of user accounts I intend to make.

Comment: can you post some more code and what the forbidden response is ect.

Comment: @ruby_newbie Good idea. I added some to clarify.

Comment: @max The dashboard class looks more like Admin::Dashboard. It's declared in /controllers/admin/dashboard.rb

Comment: `can :manage, SomeClass` is used for models where you want to grant the permission to manage any instance of a model. You could pass the path `can :manage, Admin::Dashboard` but I think you're approaching the problem wrong and it wont work as expected.

Comment: If you edit the question from a "why is'nt my code working" type question to include what you are actually trying to accomplish we might be able to give you better suggestions.

Comment: @max `can :manage, Admin::Dashboard` produces a similar error and is something I've tried already. It's also at odds with the CanCan/CanCanCan documentation.

Comment: Have you tried this method https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Authorization-for-Namespaced-Controllers ?

Comment: @sajan I had not, no. Ultimately I've decided to go with a different gem though, explained above.